# Output in ANSI while using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, batch-file, ansi-sql

I have to run a select query in SQL Server via  BAtch file and the output needs to be in ANSI format. Whenever I run, the output seems to be in Unicode. The successor job uses a exe file to which the output of the query is used as input.

I know the right-click and save as option but I am not sure how to modify the code for it. Any help would be deeply appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
type unicodefile > ansifile
```